# python selenium scrape not printing data

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to run a selenium web scrape but it is not printing the data I'm trying to get. The page will load but nothing prints in terminal. Terminal just says "DevTools listening on ws..."

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time

url = "https://www.tdameritrade.com/home.page"
username = "XXXXX"
password = "XXXXX"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   browser.get(url)

   uname = browser.find_element_by_name("tbUsername")
   uname.send_keys(username)

   passw = browser.find_element_by_name("tbPassword")
   passw.send_keys(password)

   submit_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='main-header-login-fields']//button[@class='main-header-login-submit main-header-login-label btn btn-green-solid']").click()

time.sleep(10)#delay to answer extra login/security questions

browser.get("https://invest.ameritrade.com/grid/p/site#r=jPage/https://research.ameritrade.com/grid/wwws/research/Markets/SectorsIndustries/Industry?symbol=220992436&c_name=invest_VENDOR")

cell = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="module-detail"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/span""")
print cell.text
```

EDIT:

I'm not sure where it is failing. I changed the last few lines to the code below, but terminal still just stays on "DevTools listening..." The page loads but does not print an error. Only when I close the browser will it reach and print "finished".

```
browser.get("https://invest.ameritrade.com/grid/p/site#r=jPage/https://research.ameritrade.com/grid/wwws/research/Markets/SectorsIndustries/Industry?symbol=220992436&c_name=invest_VENDOR")
try:
    browser.switch_to.window(browser.current_window_handle)
    cell = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="module-detail"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/span""")
except Exception as e:
    print e
    pass

print "finished"
```

Comment: Does the code reaches the `print`? or does it fail before?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

Before the:

```
cell = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="module-detail"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/span""")
```

Line add

```
browser.switch_to.window(browser.current_window_handle)
```

Then it try again. Hope this will helps you! :)